# Storing multiple values in single property of Neo4j Lucene index

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j, multivalue

I want to store multiple values in a single index property of neo4j Lucene index, e.g.

```
IndexName: profile

property- Education: "Stanford University, Grad School", "Harvard University, MS"
property- Work: "Nokia Siemens Networks", "Motorola"
```

Search should also work in all cases like `and`, `or`.

We can do such a thing with Solr setting the property as multi-valued attribute. I'm not sure about neo4j + Lucene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add String[] array values to an index (just as with nodes/relationships) and it will index each item in the array separately and I think that will solve your problem.

```
  Index myIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes( "profile" );
  myIndex.add( myNode, "Education", new String[] {"Stanford University, Grad School", "Harvard University, MS"} );
  myIndex.add( myNode, "Work", new String[] {"Nokia Siemens Networks", "Motorola"} );
  // Query for it (remember the quote escaping)
  myIndex.query( "Education:\"Stanford University, Grad School\" AND Work:Motorola" );
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Took me some time to find this thread and figure it out.. Does it exist in the Neo4j documentation? I did not find anything!